# Failed to import multiple csv files into pandas and concatenate into one DataFrame in Python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

There are about 1000 csv files under a Python project directory. I want to select 10/20 csv files from the directory, then read the selected csv file and concatenate into one DataFrame. In every csv file, there are 3 columns and 1316 rows. So, if I concat 5 csv files, the output shape should be (6575, 3). But it shows (6575, 11). Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

path = "Compressed Data/"
all_files = os.listdir(path)
random_csv_file = all_files[0:5]

li = []
for filename in random_csv_file:
  df = pd.read_csv(path+filename, index_col=None, header=0)
  li.append(df)

frames = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True, sort=False)
print(frames.shape)

# export to csv
frames.to_csv("combined_csv.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

[image: Here is the combined csv file Data]

Answer (score 0):

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('path/*.csv')]    
combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames ])
```

Comment: try checking columns names and their order.

Comment: There is no column name.

Comment: Column name of the CSV file. There must be some difference in the name. Can you share the first few rows of each CSV?

Comment: Trying adding column name so that pandas know how to group the CSVs. You can also provide the headers at the time of calling like `pd.read_csv("path/to/file.csv", names=["Sequence", "Start", End"])`

Answer (score 0):

I solved this one. So, here is the code which works perfectly.

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd

os.chdir("Compressed Data/")
fileList = glob.glob("*.csv")
fileList = fileList[0:5]
print(fileList)
dfList = []

for filename in fileList:
  df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None)
  dfList.append(df)

concatDf = pd.concat(dfList, axis=0)
print(concatDf.shape)
# export to csv
concatDf.to_csv("combined_csv.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```